# Wordpress: custom excerpt length

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to get an excerpt from each post, grabbing the first paragraph from each one. I'm currently using the ACF plugin and have custom post types and custom fields.
Here's my code:

```
function custom_field_excerpt() {
    global $post;
    $text = get_field('news');
    if ( '' != $text ) {
        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
        $excerpt_length = 20; // 20 words
        $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
    }
    return apply_filters('the_excerpt', $text);
}
```

This works great, but it only trims the first 20 words (or however many words you specify), I'm trying to adjust this to pull in the first paragraph of each post instead of the first 20 words. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because we know the content is bare (just text), you can simply explode the content via the `\n` character and then assume the first element in your new array is the first paragraph. You might be able to do this in a more efficient way but here is the function:

#### Your new function

```
function custom_field_excerpt() {
  global $post;
  $text = get_field('news');
  if ( '' != $text ) {
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
    $text_paragraphs = explode("\n",$text);
    $text = $text_paragraphs[0];
  }
  return $text;
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer, not quite though. The content is being returned like `This is an excerpt and it is twenty words long this is an excerpt and it is twenty words long...` so. It is just pulling the first 20 words from each post, regardless of the paragraphs. I'm trying to pull the first paragraph from each post, one might be 50 words long, one might be 30 etc etc. I tried the function above, but it returned all of the content from the post instead of the first paragraph.

Comment: Is the content returned within <p> tags though, or do you add those manually in your template? I'm thinking maybe just `return $text;` on  the end as I'm not sure what `apply_filters('the_excerpt',$text);` would do to my edit.

Comment: not the excerpts, no. Basically each post has its own page, these are wrapped in p tags, but the archive page, I want to display the title and a small excerpt from each post (the first paragraph) but the excerpts strips out any text formatting, including the p tags so I'm not sure if it is possible to grab the first paragraph.

Comment: Well you could simply find the `\n` in your text, that might work? Try switching my explode statement to: `explode("\n",$text);` Note: those are double quotes around the \n, and get rid of the `.'</p>'` off the next line. Let me know how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code, add it to your functions.php file

```
// Add custom excerpt length
function custom_excerpt($excerpt_length) {
    $content = get_field('custom_field_name');
        $text = strip_shortcodes( $content );
        //$text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
        $text = strip_tags($text);
        $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        if ( count($words) > $excerpt_length ) {
            array_pop($words);
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
            $text = $text . $excerpt_more;
        } else {
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
        }

    echo $text;
}
```

Then use < ?php custom_excerpt('12'); ?> to specify the length in your template
(Remove the space in the php tag above)

And for anyone else who may find this - if you are using the_content and not ACF then just change 
$content = get_field('blog_article_text');
TO
$content = get_the_content();

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace $excerpt_length with strlen($text)

```
        $text = wp_trim_words( $text, strlen($text), $excerpt_more );
```

Comment: nope, this just pulls in all the text from the post and not the first paragraph?

Comment: if the first paragraph is $post u can replace it in strlen()